# How to find the nearest point in POSTGIS?

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis

table A:

```
    lat | long | the_geom | code | sign 
    13.8433095 | 100.6360357 | 0101000020E61.... | ABC | start_point
    13.7544738 | 100.5459646 | 0101000020E6..... | ABC | end_point
    13.4124215 | 100.6232332 | 0101000020E61.... | DEF | start_point
    13.2423438 | 100.2324426 | 0101000020E6..... | DEF | end_point
```

table B:

```
lat | long | the_geom | code    
13.7546285 | 100.5458729 | 0101000020E.... | ABC    
13.7546698 | 100.5458513 | 0101000020E.... | ABC
13.7547107 | 100.5458233 | 0101000020E.... | DEF    
...
```

I would like to find the nearest point of each point (start and end pojnt) compare with every points with the same code in table B ?

What's the best PostGIS function/PostgreSQL query to solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using recent versions of the software, you can quickly find the K nearest neighbors to a point in PostGIS using KNN-GiST techniques.  Small values of K are fastest, and 1 is about as small as they get, so this should work very well for you.  I've only used KNN-GiST with text trigrams, but I know they work with PostGIS, too -- I just don't know the best page to read to get started with it.  A web search for "postgis knn gist" shows lots of likely candidates.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time question, i just found the solution of "Nearest Neighbor" 
http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=postgis_nearest_neighbor_generic